# How do I return to the Lost Bastille bonfire?

Tags: dark-souls-2

After defeating The Pursuer a giant eagle will fly you to Lost Bastille, and drop you off at a bonfire. To go further into Lost Bastille though you need to drop down a small platform, which only allows travel one-way. I've managed to clear our quite a few foes and I'd like to return to that bonfire, however I can't seem to figure out how. I've poked around online without much success, which leads me to believe I must just be missing some obvious way back.

Is there some way back to this bonfire, or will I need to make use of a homeward bone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried for a good while to find a way to get back there. No matter what I tried, though, I couldn't find a way to get back over the rubble. So, unless there's a really well-hidden trick, I'm inclined to say that it's not possible.

As consolation, however:

> if you keep pressing onward along the outside path, there's another bonfire not very far away at all.

Comment: I figured there had to be another bonfire, but I never stumbled across one. I must have just missed a door. I'll try exploring further then. I just don't want to enter that fog door which I'm sure contains a boss until I unload some of my souls, haha.

Comment: Always carry some homeward bones.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the external perimeter, in the end there will be stairs down with a barrel on top of them, in the middle of the path. Push it by running against it, it will roll down and explode on the wall at the end of the stairs revealing a hidden room with a campfire and more.

Answer (score -2):

When you enter the Lost Bastille, go up the stairs and check every door on the left when you head upstairs, eventually, you will find a bonfire over there.

Comment: This bonfire isn't accessible from the location I entered Lost Bastille from. I entered Lost Bastille from the Forest of the Fallen Giants entrance not the No-Mans Wharf entrance.